# Need to make a hex 0xff****** String darker (* = any hex char)

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I am trying to take a user inputted hex int and make it darker. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to give some context to this.  Number don't have a "darkness" property in and of themselves.  7 isn't any darker than 13 or 0xff356483.

Comment: Do you have a color in 6 byte RRGGBB form, and you want to decrease the intensity while preserving hue/saturation?

Comment: Do you mean to say "Given an RGB color as a hex number, transform it into a new hex number representing a 'darker' color"?  If so, what is meant by "darker"?  What if the color is already dark, such as 0x00202020?

Comment: i have a collor such as 0xAARRGGBB, where a stands for alpha and i need it to go from red -> darkred / blue -> darkblue etc

Comment: @user1462577 Try my answer. I'm pretty confident it will work. Just don't subtract enough to make any digit go negative.

Comment: Not to be a complete pain, but aren't hex colors normally represent RRGGBBAA format? (Maybe I just have limited experience with these things :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do binary subtraction:

```
int red = 0xff0000;
int darkerRed = (0xff0000 - 0x110000);
int programmaticallyDarkerRed;
```

You can even make it darker with a loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    programmaticallyDarkerRed = (0xff0000 - (i * 0x110000));
}
```

the closer it gets to `0x000000` or black, the darker it will be.

Comment: You probably shouldn't delete your old answer in order to post an exact duplicate.

Comment: If an answer was down voted, you should fix the problem in that answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry but no, it didnt work, it works for some but not all of the colors, here is a list of them:            public static int purple = 0xffCC33FF;
 public static int red = 0xffCC0000;
 public static int green = 0xff33CC33;
 public static int blue = 0xff3366FF;
 public static int yellow = 0xffFFFF66;
 public static int pink = 0xFFFF99FF;
 public static int white = 0xffFFFFFF;
 public static int black = 0xff000000;
 public static int grey = 0xff404040;
 public static int lightgrey = 0xffa0a0a0;
 public static int orange = 0xffFF9900;

Comment: As an aside, you should err on the side of editing your question rather than deleting it and starting over...

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Color.darker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#darker%28%29).

`Color c = Color.decode(hex).darker();`

Comment: but how would i convert it back into a hex int?

Comment: @user1462577 You can get an `int` for your argb value using [`Color.toRGB()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()) and then you can use [`Integer.toHexString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)) to convert it to a hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the hex value to a `Color` and then darken the `Color` object

```
// Convert the hex to an color (or use what ever method you want)
Color color = Color.decode(hex);

// The fraction of darkness you want to apply
float fraction = 0.1f;

// Break the color up
int red = color.getRed();
int blue = color.getBlue();
int green = color.getGreen();
int alpha = color.getAlpha();

// Convert to hsb
float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, null);
// Decrease the brightness
hsb[2] = Math.min(1f, hsb[2] * (1f - fraction));
// Re-assemble the color
Color hSBColor = Color.getHSBColor(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);

// If you need it, you will need to reapply the alpha your self
```

**UPDATE**

To get it back to hex, you could try something like

```
int r = color.getRed();
int g = color.getGreen();
int b = color.getBlue();

String rHex = Integer.toString(r, 16);
String gHex = Integer.toString(g, 16);
String bHex = Integer.toString(b, 16);

String hexValue = (rHex.length() == 2 ? "" + rHex : "0" + rHex)
                + (gHex.length() == 2 ? "" + gHex : "0" + gHex)
                + (bHex.length() == 2 ? "" + bHex : "0" + bHex);

int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

Now if that's not quite right, I'd have a look and see if there's any answers of SO or Google

Comment: but how do i get it back into a hex int? 8 bit